# Is the IP address the same when logging in via SSH in GCP VM instance through the browser?

Tags: linux, networking, google-cloud-platform, ssh

I have a VM instance on Google Cloud Platform running on a OpenLiteSpeed web server with a WordPress installation, the OS would be Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Generally, I login via the browser console. However since this can be done from any machine with access to my Google Account, I figured that I would like to set additional protection, therefore I executed the following two commands in the terminal:

```
sudo ufw deny 22
sudo ufw allow from [my_ip_here] proto tcp to any port 22
```

When I restarted the SSH browser terminal, the access was refused with a status code 4003, as if the IP I am logging in is not the same, which would not be the case.

In this scenario, am I doing something wrong, am I missing something or the methodology used to connect is different?

Generally, if I don't setup any SSH keys, would the security be enough so that only I can login to the connection via the browser only?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Whenever VM in GCE is restarted it changes external IP. You can [External static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address). Does your GCP firewall would allow access from specific IP ranges? How are you connecting to VM (which command, which OS), methonds mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/access-overview)? Are you using `gclud compute ssh` or maybe 3rd party software like `putty`?

Comment: My goal is to simply limit the SSH access to my device only and to the browser only. I haven't configured the GCP firewall yet, it is using the default settings set upon the creation of the VM, I am adding restriction rules via the ufw as demonstrated in the code lines in the opening post. I am using the SSH button to login, described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser) , for the moment I am not using any external 3rd party client to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to be able to use browser SSH from *your* machine but disable it for everyone else.
Traffic for SSH from the browser doesn't come from your IP, take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#network-reqs) and note the last point about IP addresses. It's either globally enabled or globally disabled.
If you need a restricted GUI logon then `xrdp` might work, assuming your VM has a GUI installed.

Comment: I understand, thank you for clarifying. That actually explains a lot, I was baffled by the last login's IP upon loading the VM, as who.is returned that it was a Google IP. Now that you have provided me with the info, I can understand how it actually works, thank you.